# Nuget showing incorrect version as latest

Tags: package, nuget, pack

I finally managed to create a nuget package and publish it with the command line,
currently I have it set it up to get the package version from this attribute:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.*")]
```

and everything is working except for the fact that my latest two pushes are not showing as the latest version and instead and old version is still showing as the latest:

[image: incorrect latest package]

So I'm wondering, did I do something wrong? , 1.0.0.5917 should be the default package but it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet is showing the correct latest version since 1.0.0.26045 is greater than 1.0.0.5917.

The problem is that you are using an asterisk for the fourth digit which is the revision number. According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) this number is generated based on the following rule:

> The default revision number is the number of seconds since midnight local time (without taking into account time zone adjustments for daylight saving time), divided by 2.

So it will not always be higher in value depending on what time during the day you build the assembly.